# Is there a way to view who created a tag?

Tags: discussion

I recently created a tag and I am wondering if we can actually see who created the tag. Clicking on Tag info gives information like tagged questions,related tags,Top Askers,Top Answerers. Is there a way to see the creator of the tag?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know is to look up the oldest question holding the tag, and checking out the revision history.

I'm not sure whether that method is accurate.

Comment: It isn't. The tag could've been created today, and a 5 year old question be edited later with the tag.